# How to get top 50 countries and leave the rest of the countries grouped to others in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to see TOP 50 countries, remaining countries need to be grouped as other countries using CASE statement. IS that possible to do? Please suggest.

Comment: Why does it need to be a case statement?

Comment: Also, which SQL dialect are you talking about? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Based on the keyword `TOP`, I'd guess SQL Server but that's not a guarantee.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions and aggregation

```
select (case when seqnum <= 50 then country else 'others' end) as country,
       sum(?)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by ?) desc as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (case when seqnum <= 50 then country else 'others' end)
order by 2 desc;
```

`?` is for the column that you care about.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response !  instead of having seqnum can we do it using top keyword?

Comment: No, because TOP will limit the results, and you asked to group the rest of the countries, not discard them.